# Flickr API PHP getPhotoSets Description

Tags: php, flickr, galleria

I'm trying to integrate the Flickr API with Jquery Gallerific. If you're familiar with Gallerific you know photos in the Gallery can have a caption. I'm trying to pull photos from a specific set from a user using flickr.photosets.getPhotos to get thumbnails. However, with this method it's not possible to get description for each thumbnail, only for the set so I'm having to run flickr.photos.getInfo for each photo in the set, which works but is pretty much useless as a page takes 10+ seconds to load. Does anyone know how to obtain flickr photos from a set with the individual description for each photo? I've looked through the API but can't seem to find anything.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never actually used the Flickr API but what about just loading the thumbnails initially, then using JSONP (or a custom "proxy" of sorts) to query photo information asynchronously after the page has loaded.  Or, better yet, when the user actually hovers over an image.

Comment: I'm real lazy so I didn't want to resort to doing this, thinking about it, it won't take that much work to do, so thanks!